# Checking the opening hours by condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have little problem with my script.

**ad_otwarcie** (row in database) - opening time of the restaurant

**ad_zamkniecie** (row in database) - restaurant closing time

```
$current_time = date('H:i'); // checks current time
$closed_soon = date("H:i", strtotime("-5 minutes", strtotime($row['ad_zamkniecie']))); // closing time - 5 mins

if($current_time >= date($row['ad_otwarcie']) && $current_time <= date($row['ad_zamkniecie'])) {
  echo "The place (ex. restaurant) is open";
} elseif($current_time >= $closed_soon && $current_time <= date($row['ad_zamkniecie']) ) {
  echo "The place (ex. restaurant) will close in 5 mins";
} elseif($current_time >= date($row['ad_zamkniecie'])) {
  echo "The place (ex. restaurant) is closed";
}
```

If there is no middle condition (I mean the one regarding closing the restaurant in 5 minutes) all is well. Conversely, if that adds up, it becomes a problem. It doesn't tell me "restaurant will close in 5 minutes" but only "restaurant open".

I would like to make it work.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of `ad_otwarcie` and `ad_zamkniecie`. I don't understand how you are passing `ad_otwarcie` to the `date` function in the if statement.

Comment: @JacobMulquin ad_otwarcie "17:00", ad_zamkniecie "19:00" so i know the resutarant will open at 17:00 and close at 19:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the times to the `date` function in your if statements. You only need to compare the strings themselves. You can also put the logic in a function to simplify:

```
<?php

$open_time = '09:00';
$close_time = '17:00';

function place_open_status($open_time, $close_time, $current_time = null)
{
    if (is_null($current_time))
        $current_time = date('H:i');
    
    $closed_soon = date('H:i', strtotime('-5 minutes', strtotime($close_time)));

    if ($current_time >= $open_time && $current_time < $closed_soon)
        return ['open', 'The place (ex. restaurant) is open'];
    
    if ($current_time >= $closed_soon && $current_time < $close_time)
        return ['closing_soon','The place (ex. restaurant) will close in 5 mins'];

    return ['closed','The place (ex. restaurant) is closed'];
}

var_dump('Should be open: ' . place_open_status($open_time, $close_time, '10:00')[0]);
var_dump('Should be closing_soon: ' . place_open_status($open_time, $close_time, '16:58')[0]);
var_dump('Should be closed: ' . place_open_status($open_time, $close_time, '17:24')[0]);

while (...) {
    $status = place_open_status($row['ad_otwarcie'], $row['ad_zamkniecie']);
    echo '<div class="exampleclass '.$status[0].'">'.$status[1].'</div>';
}
```

This will return:

```
string(20) "Should be open: open"
string(36) "Should be closing_soon: closing_soon"
string(24) "Should be closed: closed"
```

Comment: It will work in my while? because i had put it in while

Comment: The function does not have to go into the while, but you could do `echo place_open_status($row['ad_otwarcie'], $row['ad_zamkniecie'])` in the while.

Comment: Wow it worked! but brother i have last question - how can i do something like - if "closed" then return "closed" and return $text = "test" which "test" will be class name for div

like <div class='exampleclass ". $text ."'> - but it will shows only when restaurant is closed

Comment: @Zimnytu I've updated my answer. You can return an array from the function that has the "status code" and then also the "message". This means you will have `exampleclass open`, `exampleclass closing_soon`, `exampleclass closed`. Please mark answer as accepted and upvote if you can :)